# EditText tint line color not changing in night mode

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-dark-theme

I have `EditText` in my layout

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/etMarks1"
 style="@style/Marks"/>
```

and `theme.xml`

```
    <style name="Marks" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:layout_weight">15</item>
        <item name="android:ems">1</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">number</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

The tint line color is black by default and it should change it's color in night mode, But it is not changing.

I tried to manually define the tint line color in theme.xml(nignt)

```
<item name ="backgroundTint">@color/white</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
```

But, it is not working,
Any Solution for this ?

Comment: the default parent style of the EditText is Widget.AppCompat.EditText. and if you want to override the colorControlNormal you have to use android:theme and not style

Comment: Yeah, now  I defined colorControlNormal in theme.xml(night) and working fine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** 
I defined `colorControlNormal` in my application's default theme, working fine.